# Comparable vs Number, Design choice

Tags: java, abstract-class, generic-programming

I have a class which have a structure like

```
class A {
    String key;
    Double value;
}
```

Now the value could be double, long, int, fraction and so on.

How should I handle this in the same class?

Shall I make value a `Comparable` or `Number`?

Number as these values are extending Number, Comparable as i want this class [and value] to be comparable.

Comment: How would you use it? ```Comparable``` seems like an odd choice to me...

Comment: If you want this class to be comparable, you should show that by saying `class A implements Comparable<A>`.

Comment: Why not just store `value` as `BigDecimal`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to make the class with a generic type `<T extends Number>`.

```
class A<T extends Number> {
    String key;
    T value;
}
```

Comment: So if i instantiate like A ("a" , 2.0d), how would this be handled ?

Comment: Should be `new A<>("a", 2.0)` or `new A<>("a", 2d)`. You are missing the `<>`. Specifying `2.0d` is overkill as `2.0` and `2d` are both `double` literals.

Comment: @NooB8374, if you call a contructor (`A<Double> o = new A<>("a", 2.0d);`), it will work fine (autoboxing is in action) (Andreas, thanks)

Comment: @Andreas, you are missing the `2.` :)

Comment: Got it. How would i implement compareTo in this class?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko You're right. Don't think I've ever seen anyone do that, though. *(other than you, right now)*

Comment: @NooB8374 That's a brand new requirement, that totally changes the question.

Comment: Should have mentioned in question. :|

Comment: @NooB8374 So should `2d`, `2L` and `2` be considered equal?

Comment: Idealy yes. But i am ok if they are not .

Answer (score 2):

You can use `generics` and have both

```
class A<T extends Number & Comparable<T>> {
    String key;
    T value;

    public A(String key, T value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Since `Number` is not `Comparable`, you can use `intersection types` as shown above on the type parameter `T` (Integer, Long, Double) would be happy with this, and now value is a `Number` and a `Comparable`

Answer (score 1):

It only depends on the assumptions you want or need to make about the value type:

- Go for a generic type `T` if you will store only values of some type `T` fixed in each use context.
- Use `Number` if instances need to be flexible in terms of the value type only requiring it to be numeric.
- Use `Comparable` if you need the values to compare.
- Use `Object` if you do not need to assume anything particular about the values.

Answer (score 1):

I can't add comment yet so... If you do as what [Andrew's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37172532/5582311) said, the initialization would be something like `new A<Double>("a", 2.0d)`. Personally I prefer define value as `Number`.